# Cannot get CORS to work in Visual Studio (works on DEV pair of servers, won’t work on TEST pair of servers)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, controller, cors, webapi

We have split servers – WEBAPI’s on a separate server.  I got my app working across split servers in DEV, but I’ve moved the same code to the pair of TEST servers and it’s not working.  I cannot figure out why.  It seems like it must be something different with the TEST WebApi server but I don’t know where to look and don’t have access to it to look under the hood without asking systems people to do it for me.

Software being used: Visual Studio 2017, C#, Javascript, HTML/CSS, Oracle, Entity Framework 6, Breeze, IIS 10

I installed NuGet packages: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.2.7, and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors 2.2.0.

In my \WebAPI\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs, I added the EnableCors:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.EnableCors();

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

And in my BREEZE and MVC Controllers, I added the EnableCors with the 3 origins for DEV, TEST, and PREPROD environments (I did discover that the presence of the [Authorize] attribute causes it not to work.  Had to comment that out):

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace SCC.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    //[Authorize]    
    [BreezeController]
    [EnableCors(origins: “http://webdevint.scc.state.va.us,http://in.scctest2new.scc.state.va.us,http://in.sccpreweb5.scc.state.va.us", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class LookupController : ApiController
    {
```

DEV is working, TEST is not.

On DEV – I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header required by CORS:

Origin (in my EnableCors): WEBDEVINT server --> Webapi: SCCDEVCS server

[image]

On TEST – I get an error:

Origin (in my EnableCors): SCCTEST2NEW server --> Webapi: SCCTESTAPP server

```
ERROR: “Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://scctestapp.scc.state.va.us/EFIWEBAPI/breeze/Lookup/Metadata' from origin 'http://in.scctest2new.scc.state.va.us' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.”
```

If I drop in the URL it’s trying to reach into the address bar: `'http://scctestapp.scc.state.va.us/EFIWEBAPI/breeze/Lookup/Metadata',`

it works just fine.  Returns the metadata.  So I know the URL being requested is correct.

Note:  I also tried the following in my Controllers and it didn’t work any differently - I know that's a bit of a security risk to allow any server to originate messages:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

It seems like there is something different on the TEST server vs. the DEV server.  But I had the two webapps (UI and WebAPI) set up in IIS exactly the same way on DEV and on TEST.

Could it be an IIS setting that needs to be set?  Could it be something in the GAC?  I don’t know where to start looking.  Thanks for any advice.

Edit:
I also tried adding the following lines to the WebAPI web.config with and without the Credentials line:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://in.scctest2new.scc.state.va.us" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

But it gives me a 401 Unauthorized on the Metadata call.  Not sure what Credentials it's looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in Startup.cs setting some thing like that

```
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                //context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
                await next.Invoke();
            });
            app.UseCors(
              options => options.WithOrigins("http://117.1.16.24",
                            "http://10.47.102.60",
                            "http://10.47.102.61",
                            "http://10.47.102.62",
                            "http://10.47.102.63")
                          .AllowAnyOrigin()
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowCredentials()
            );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with this.  I don't have a Startup.cs.  I have tried something similar in the WebAPI web.config by adding these lines:

Comment: <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://in.scctest2new.scc.state.va.us" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
But that gives me a 401 Unauthorized when the Metadata tries to run.  Not sure what Credentials it's looking for. Also, I didn't need this to successfully work on DEV servers.

Comment: I just added the above code in an edit to the original question so it's more readable.

Comment: Are you using .Net Core ? or .Net Frame Work ?

Comment: Do you try put     [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] on top of single function in controller

Comment: Excellent idea.  Unfortunately, no change.  Same error.  Here's my code.

Comment: Oh sorry.  Can't format code in a comment.  Anyhow, I put the  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] right before the Metadata method and the Lookups method in the LookupController.  This is so strange.

Comment: Finally figured it out!!!  But not sure how to fix.

IIS settings on WebAPI server where it works (DEV):
Enabled: Anonymous Authentication 
Disabled:ASP.NET Impersonation, Forms Authentication and Windows Authentication

IIS settings on WebAPI server where it doesn't work (TEST):
Enabled: Windows Authentication 
Disabled: ASP.NET Impersonation, Anonymous Authentication, Forms Authentication

I asked them to ENABLE Anonymous on TEST server and CORS is working!!!  

Only problem is that when Anonymous is enabled, my impersonation to write to another fileshare stops working.

Comment: So not sure how to set IIS so that both impersonation and CORS will work???  Any suggestions?  I need to research the Anonymous and Impersonation settings.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response here code example :  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class LienThongController : ApiController

Answer (score 0):

Here code for controller class

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class LienThongController : ApiController
```

and there is function

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Unit/getList")]
        public IHttpActionResult getListUnitLienThong()
```

Web API Config

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors(); 
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't help with the impersonation problem, does it?  I discovered my CORS code is working if I turn IIS Anonymous Authentication ON.  But that causes my impersonation, needed to enable the code to write an XML file out to a fileshare, to stop working.  So I'm down to trying to figure out how to impersonation to work with anonymous authentication ON.

Comment: So, being sure [Authorize] attribute was commented out and being sure IIS Anonymous Authentication was ON made the CORS finally work.

Comment: Now my problem is getting the impersonation back to working.  I probably should start a new ticket for that, unless you have some ideas.  I'm thinking maybe put out a new IIS app pool with my own id and pwd  as the anonymous user, so anonymous can be turned on to make CORS work, but the user is the one I need for impersonation.

Comment: No just declare Authorize tag to function you want to make Authorize working something like this:     
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Unit/getList")]
        public IHttpActionResult getListUnitLienThong()

and some function not using Authorize 
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Unit/getAgenciesList")]
        public IHttpActionResult getAgenciesList()
don't push Authorize tag to class controller is make all function in class Authorize

Comment: you can contact with me vietdq1291@gmail.com if you need check your code

Comment: That's good advice.  Thanks.  I've always just had it at the top of the Controller.  Never thought of putting on individual functions.